# How to install MongoDB as a service on Windows 10

Tags: mongodb, windows-10

I want to install MongoDB on my Windows 10 (x64) machine.I've downloaded "Windows 64 bit 2008 R2 +" version.. from MongoDB site.

Problem is, it installed as a 32-bit application.. don't know why
C:\Program files (x86)\

I'm unable to configure Mongo as a Service...
Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is going wrong, exactly? Is there some error message you are getting?